# In R/waterfalls, when `fill_by_sign = TRUE` , how to change the fill colour group by 'sign'

Tags: r, waterfall

In R/waterfalls, when `fill_by_sign = TRUE` , the positive columns fill in 'green' and negative columns fill in 'red'。If I want positive columns fill in 'white', negative columns fill in 'pink',how can i do it ? Thanks!

```
 library(waterfalls)

plot_data <- data.frame(category = letters[1:5],
                        value = c(1, -0.2, 0.3, -0.1, -0.15))

waterfall(.data = plot_data,
          fill_by_sign = TRUE,
          calc_total = TRUE,
          total_axis_text='total')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it by creating a vector that checks the sign of the value and assigns a color based on the sign. Then you can feed that into the *fill_colors* argument.

```
color_vector <- ifelse(plot_data$value > 0, "white", "pink")

waterfall(.data = plot_data,
          fill_by_sign = FALSE,
          fill_colours = color_vector,
          calc_total = TRUE,
          total_axis_text='total')
```